# How to edit the index of a pointer array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, indexing

Ok so I am curious as to how you would go about using a pointer array to access a value in the index. Like for example:

```
printf("%c", (*character)[0]);
```

I know I have this code wrong, but I have know clue how to fix it. Say I want to access the 0 position in the pointer array and then print it like above, how would I do it?

Comment: Provide the definition of `character`.

Comment: "using a pointer array to access a value in the index" - I don't understand this.

Comment: It is just a general description of an array I could create that stores characters. Like char character[4] = {a, b, c, d}. If the array was a pointer, how would I access the 0 index and possibly change it if I felt like it?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming character is `char character[] = {'1'};`

```
character[someIndex] means someIndex[character] means  *(character+someIndex)
```

If that is what you wanted to know. So you should be doing something like:

```
printf("%c", *(character+0));
```

Which is equivalent to

```
printf("%c", *character);

printf("%c", character[0]);
```

Just missed out - regarding this statement

> index of a pointer array?

Please know [Arrays are not Pointers](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html). If that is where you were confused.

Comment: @Smac89 For the same reason you added parentheses.

Comment: @Smac89 :: Just to make the OP understand.

Comment: @Acme

But this will be misleading because say the array pointer is pointing to the kth element, doing `*(character+0)` will not print the first element

Comment: Ah yes! This is what I was looking for! I had no clue what the syntax was. Thanks so much! And yeah it does actually print the first element. I just tested it out.

Comment: @Smac89 :: Why cannot k be equal to 0? `character` is the base address of the array - assuming if its a pointer it should point to the same address otherwise doing something like this makes no sense.

Comment: @Acme

Take a look at [this](http://ideone.com/abbaNg)

Comment: @Smac89 :: You are arguing over something pointless - Please see - what is meant by the "equivalence of pointers and arrays" here http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

Comment: Oh, Yes I knew that arrays were not pointers. What I failed to communicate was that I had an array that I assigned a pointer to. So in my mind I was thinking a "pointer to an array". I'm a bit new to programming so forgive my communication.

Comment: @BrandonBraun :: Thankyou - and if you can please select my answer if this fixed your problem this will get me some points for helping you :)

Answer (score 1):

From your question I observe that you have declare a character pointer something like this
`char *character="something";`
and now you want access its contents by indexing.
So why worrying,No matter whether you have declare  pointer array or array.You can access its contents by any of following way:-
`printf("%c",character[1]);`  //general method
or by pointer notation
`printf("%c",*(character+1));`
or
 
`printf("%c",*(1+character));`//commutative law
or more surprisingly you can use following method too
`printf("%c",1[character]);`

Answer (score 1):

char *arr[20]={"Stackoverflow"};

This means you have an char type pointer array where 20 memory location's addresses are stored in an 20 size array. 1st memory location in arr[0] points to the string "Stackoverflow" and rest of them are not assigned(so you will get garbage value or maybe segmentation fault). Now, if you want to access 0th memory location just do this:

printf("%s\n",arr[0]);